# Python: How to loop using a for loop more times than there are items in the file

Tags: python, file, line

```
theFile   = open('theFile', 'r+')
fileCheck = open('fileCheck', 'r+')

numOfFiles = 3
currentNum = 0

def check():
    for i in theFile:
        for lines in fileCheck:
            if i == lines:
                print("We already have " + i)
                break 
            else:
                print("We don't have " + i)
                break

check()

fileCheck.close()
theFile.close()
```

---

fileCheck contents are:

```
line 1
line 2
line 4
line 5
```

theFile contents are:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10
```

I am trying to loop through both files to check if the contents from `theFile` are in `fileCheck`.  For example, if `"line 1"` is already in `fileCheck`, I want it to ignore that and keep moving.  When it gets to `"line 3"` which is not in `fileCheck`, I want it to do a series of code, then when it gets to `"line 4"` it should skip it and `"line 5"`, too.  From line 6-10 it performs the code I tell it to do. I know this is not working because there are only 4 lines in `fileCheck` so it only performs that loop 4 times, and doesn't get all 10 lines. I want it to loop through all 10 lines but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
for i in theFile:
    for lines in fileCheck:
        ...
```

it looks like you're trying to iterate over fileCheck more than once. In that case, you will have to reset it somehow (for example, repeat the

```
fileCheck = open('fileCheck', 'r+')
```

but you could start by reading the whole file at once:

```
fileCheck = list(open('fileCheck', 'r+')
```

Have you considered doing

```
theFile = set(open('theFile, 'r+'))
fileCheck = set(open('fileCheck', 'r+'))
```

and then using set differences: `theFile - fileCheck` are the lines that are in the first but not the second set; `line in theFile` is True or False, and so on.